# use ISODate in mongodb with play morphia

Tags: mongodb, playframework, morphia

I want to save the Date type of value to mongodb as ISODate or any similar date type with play-morphia. However, when i try to save the following class to mongodb, it throws an exception on lastcheckin. And when i change its type to String, it worked fine. Is it because i didn't use the correct data type in JAVA to map to the ISODate in mongodb?

```
@Entity(value = "devices", noClassnameStored = true)
public class Device {
    public String ip;
    public String mac;
    public Date lastcheckin;
}
```

Assign the current date to lastcheckin property

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
try {
        device.lastcheckin = sdf.parse(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString());
    }
catch (ParseException e){
        PlayLogger.instance().info(e.getMessage());
}
```

Got the following stacktrace

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.google.code.morphia.mapping.ValueMapper.fromDBObject(ValueMapper.java:27)
    at com.google.code.morphia.mapping.Mapper.readMappedField(Mapper.java:497)
    at com.google.code.morphia.mapping.Mapper.fromDb(Mapper.java:480)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.util.Date.parse(Date.java:615)
    at com.google.code.morphia.converters.DateConverter.decode(DateConverter.java:32)
    at com.google.code.morphia.converters.DefaultConverters.fromDBObject(DefaultConverters.java:129)
    at com.google.code.morphia.mapping.ValueMapper.fromDBObject(ValueMapper.java:25)
    ... 53 more
```

Comment: If you want help fixing/diagnosing an exception, it helps to provide the actual stack trace.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're doing all that toString()/parse() work.  `device.lastcheckin = new Date()` should work just fine.

Comment: @evanchooly, I want to store the date with correct format.

Comment: Dates have no format when they're Dates.  Formatting only applies to the stringified display forms.  You're doing pointless work there it seems.

Answer (score 0):

This should be fine in general as long as it's `java.util.Date`.

PS: The `public` attributes should be made `private` / `protected` plus getters and setters.

Comment: Ok, this is an ancient version, please update to https://github.com/mongodb/morphia. And you are showing the String version in your code, right?